# Placement of nicht

Tags: sentence-structure

Of these two sentences:

1. Die Kinder brauchen heute in die Schule nicht zu gehen.
2. Die Kinder brauchen heute nicht in die Schule zu gehen.

Which one is correct and why?
I'm assuming number one, since the object should be contained in the brauchen... nicht zu + infinitiv, right?
Apparently the website I was doing the exercises on and my Austrian girlfriend have different opinions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "object" ("in die Schule" is a directional adverbial, not an object) and what you mean by "contained in...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variant that sounds most normal (in a neutral context) is 2. Here, "in die Schule zu gehen" is probably a unit, i.e. a compound predicate. It also contains the sentence stress ("in die SCHUle zu gehen"). So when you negate the meaning of the sentence, "nicht" is placed in front of that.

It is possible to use the word order in 1 (though it may sound clumsy), but the stress pattern has to adapt. Here you need narrow focus on "gehen", in this case probably understood as "walk / zu Fuß gehen".

- "Die Kinder brauchen heute in die Schule nicht zu GEHEN"

may mean that someone will drive them to school instead. This is a narrow focus, so it is just about the contrast "gehen" with some other activity. Everything else is given and therefore precedes the negation.

In general, negation usually precedes a stressed part of the clause and says that you actually want something that is in contrast with this information. Therefore, the position of "nicht" is variable, it depends on what you want to negate, and it is closely connected with the placement of stress. The Duden grammar (2022 ed.) puts it as follows (p. 254): "Zum Fokusbereich: Negierte Sätze äußert man gewöhnlich nicht einfach ins Blaue hinein – normalerweise will man damit eine Aussage oder eine Erwartung korrigieren, und zwar meist nicht zur Gänze. Vielmehr steht gewöhnlich ein Teil der Aussage im Zentrum der Aufmerksamkeit. Um zu einem zutreffenden, nicht verneinten Satz zu gelangen, muss man nur diesen Teil korrigieren. Man spricht hier vom Fokusbereich der Negation... [in sum]: Die Negationspartikel "nicht" steht am linken Rand ihres Fokusbereichs."

Comment: I find *die Kinder brauchen heute in die Schule nicht zu GEHen* really bad. Even if you wanted narrow focus on *gehen*, you would still say *die Kinder brauchen heute nicht in die Schule zu GEHen*.

Comment: @DavidVogt: that may be, but since emphasis is not shown in writing I concur with what Alazon said. Your sentence either means what you intended it to mean - because it is the "neutral word order" - or they don't have to go to school - but maybe somewhere else. See also [https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72960/about-time-manner-place/72962#72962 here]

Comment: Thank you! Very clear.

Answer (score 2):

The normal sentence is

> Heute brauchen die Kinder nicht in die Schule zu gehen

The "in die Schule gehen" is somewhat a compound verb or verb with adverbial which is not separated usually. However, one *can* place the "nicht" in between, but then it implies something slightly different:

> Heute brauchen die Kinder in die Schule nicht zu gehen (sondern heute fahren alle mit dem Rad / fahren mit dem Boot, weil die Schule auf der anderen Warft auf der Hallig ist und gerade Land unter / etc)

Or whatever oddity. But even in these cases it sounds a bit awkward and one would only use it this way in a somewhat joking manner to get only moderately funny word plays like these.

Answer (score 0):

If a clause has a directional adverbial or prepositional object, those are usually seen as an integral part of the verb phrase and thus, *nicht* is placed in front of them even if you want to negate the action.

> Du weißt, dass die Kinder heute nicht in die Schule gehen.
>
> Die Kinder gehen heute nicht in die Schule.

> Du weißt, dass die Kinder heute nicht auf den Bus warten
>
> Die Kinder warten heute nicht auf den Bus.

If you place *nicht* in front of the verb, it emphasizes the kind of action.

> Du weißt, dass die Kinder heute in die Schule nicht gehen, sondern fahren.

But you can't do that with directions if the *nicht* would end up lonely at the end as that sounds too odd.

> <strike>Die Kinder gehen heute in die Schule nicht.</strike>

It's less awkward with a prepositional object.

> Du weißt, dass die Kinder heute auf den Bus nicht warten, sondern ihm entgegenlaufen.
>
> Die Kinder warten heute auf den Bus nicht, sondern laufen ihm entgegen.