# Stellung von Ergänzungen im Dativ und Akkusativ

Tags: sentence-structure

Ein Lehrer hat mir Übungen gegeben, bei denen die Ergänzung im Dativ *immer* vor die im Akkusativ geht:

> Gestern hat der Mann *der Frau das Buch* gegeben.

Aber es scheint, dass es komplizierter sein mag.  Ein [anderes Buch](https://www.schubert-verlag.de/c-grammatik.php) behauptet,

1:

> Verwenden die Nomen das gleiche Artikelwort (z.B. den bestimmten
> Artikel), steht normalerweise die Ergänzung im Dativ vor der Ergänzung
> im Akkusativ.

Und 2:

> Bei unterschiedlichen Artikelwörtern steht in der Regel das Nomen mit unbestimmtem Artikel nach dem Nomen mit bestimmtem
> Artikel

Also hat man

> Ich habe dem Kollegen das Computerprogramm erklärt.

bzw.

> Ich habe das Computerprogramm einem Kollegen erklärt.

Ist das immer richtig, dass die zweite “Regel" Priorität vor der ersten hat, so dass der zweite Satz richtig ist?

Comment: Die Reihenfolge von Dativ- und Akkusativobjekt unterliegt keinen "harten" Regeln. Sie wird nur Sprachlernern so erklärt, damit sie keine (eventuell unbeabsichtigte) Betonung in den Satz einbauen, deswegen bringt man ihnen die "neutrale" Version bei. Beide Varianten sind richtig, tragen aber in der Reihenfolge eine Zusatzbedeutung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leider ist es nicht ganz so einfach. Der unbestimmte Artikel kann verschiedene Bedeutungen signalisieren, und die Bedeutungen zählen. Die Regel ist eigentlich: Bekannte Information vor neuer Information. Die Regel ist also inhaltlich und geht nicht einfach nach der Wortart.

In dem Beispielsatz "ich habe das Programm einem Kollegen erklärt" wird also der Kollege neu eingeführt. Das ist eine typische Funktion des Artikels "einem". Man kann es aber umdrehen: "Ich habe einem Kollegen das Computerprogramm erklärt". Diese Reihenfolge würde man zum Beispiel wählen, wenn man selber zwar an einen bestimmten Kollegen denkt, den man kennt und nur gerade nicht sagt, wer es ist. Das sind sehr feine Unterschiede :). Am günstigsten ist es, sich an einem Fragetest zu orientieren: Wenn man ein Fragewort einführt, dann steht das immer für die Information, die gerade am interessantesten und neuesten ist. Es gibt dann in der Antwort verschiedene Abfolgen, weil sie zu verschiedenen Fragen passen:

- **Wem** hast du das Programm erklärt? - (Ich habe das Programm) **einem Kollegen** (erklärt).
- **Was** hast du heute nachmittag in der Firma zu tun gehabt? - (Ich musste einem Kollegen) **das Computerprogramm erklären.**

Die Sache hängt damit zusammen, dass die Einheit vor dem Verb am Satzende normalerweise auch die Betonung erhält.

Wenn beide Objekte denselben Status haben, dann gibt es eine Grundreihenfolge. Bei den meisten Verben ist das tatsächlich "Dativ vor Akkusativ" (es hängt vom Verb ab, welche Reihenfolge es verlangt). Die Grundreihenfolge ist die, die keine besondere Betonung hat und keine starke Zweiteilung des Satzes in alt-neu (zum Beispiel wenn alles neu ist, was man sagt, oder wenn alle Objekte gleich bekannt sind und nur das Verb die neue Information ist). Wenn besondere Betonungen oder Kontraste ausgedrückt werden sollen, dann wird die Reihenfolge geändert, und diese Abweichung von der Grundreihenfolge ist das Signal, dass etwas besonders zu betonen ist.

Answer (score 1):

Wir hatten dasselbe Thema schon öfter: die deutsche Satzstellung ist (vor allem verglichen mit der englischen) sehr frei und die Anordnung der Objekte dient hauptsächlich dazu, Betonung zu transportieren. Hier ist [ein Thread dazu](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72960/about-time-manner-place).

Um Dein eigenes Beispiel zu verwenden:

> Gestern hat der Mann der Frau das Buch gegeben.

Das ist korrekt und *eine* Möglichkeit. Hier ist eine andere, ebenso korrekte:

> Das Buch hat gestern der Mann der Frau gegeben.

Hier ist die Betonung auf "Buch" - an anderen Tagen hat er ihr vielleicht was anderes gegeben, aber *gestern*, da wars *das Buch*.

> *Der Frau* hat der Mann das Buch gestern gegeben.

Betonung: Frau. Jeden Tag gibt der Mann das Buch jemand anderem, aber gestern, da bekam es die Frau.

Nicht nur das *erste* Objekt kann die Betonung bekommen, auch das letzte. Eine alternative Bedeutung der obigen Stellung könnte auch sein, daß die Betonung auf "gestern" liegt. Etwa so:

> Q: Der Mann hat das Buch oft verborgt, wann bekam es die Frau?
> A: *Der Frau* hat der Mann das Buch *gestern* gegeben.

Oder, eine andere Variante:

> Der Frau hat gestern das Buch der Mann gegeben.

Die Frau kriegt jeden Tag von irgendwem das Buch, gestern aber, da hat es ihr *der Mann* gegeben.

Und da gibt es noch jede Menge weiterer Möglichkeiten.

Comment: Danke.  Ich habe immer gedacht, wie du soeben erwähnt hast, dass die betonte Information an erster Stelle geht. Aber wichtige Information -- _neue_ Information -- kann offenbar auch am Ende des Mittelfelds stehen.  Also, auf den beiden Stellen?